# The cancel button doesn't work for this code

Tags: excel, vba

I've found this code for Microsoft Visual Basic Editor that opens multiple links in excel. However, I can't cancel it when the range prompt appears. Any ideas?

```
    Sub OpenMultipleLinks()
 'From WindowsLoop
     Dim MultiLink As Hyperlink
     Dim SelectedRng As Range
     On Error Resume Next
     'Window Heading
     WLTitleId = "WL Open Multiple Links"
     'Set Range
     Set SelectedRng = Application.Selection
     Set SelectedRng = Application.InputBox("Range", WLTitleId, SelectedRng.Address, Type:=8)
     'Open Links One by One
     For Each MultiLink In SelectedRng.Hyperlinks
         MultiLink.Follow
     Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: try checking for `If SelectedRng = Nothing` right after the `Set SelectedRng = Application.InputBox("Range", WLTitleId, SelectedRng.Address, Type:=8)`

Comment: This doesn't work. The code isn't recognized as correct.

Comment: Sorry it should have been `If SelectedRng Is Nothing Then.....`   
I've also added an answer with the code  EDIT:(Well was in the process of doing so when the question was closed)